# Unmounting ReactJS element

Tags: reactjs

I have created an element with ReactJS and appended it to `div` container and then removed the same element using `jQuery.remove()`.

Do I need to unmount the node that I created with React?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should do so. You can remove the element by

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('divsId'));
```

where the div you are removing the element from has to be the one you were originaly appending it to.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you don't do it?

Comment: I think, but don't kill me if I'm wrong -  that if you don't unmount it, the element keeps receiving updates on state changes which will decrease the pages performance. @andrerpena

Answer (score 1):

Interfering with the DOM causes unnecessary repainting and redrawing which are expensive processes. The best method is to set a flag like so:

```
getInitialState() {
 isVisible: false
}

toggleVisiblity() {
 var {isVisible} = this.state
 this.setState({isVisible: !isVisible})
}

render() {
 if(isVisible)
  var display = <h2> Your content </h2>
 return(
  <button onClick={this.toggleVisibility}> Click here </button>
  {display}
 )
}
```

When isVisible is false, React automatically unmounts and when it is true, it mounts. This is a good practice to maybe even add animations.